# Google Identity Services: What stops someone else using my client ID?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, websecurity

For traditional oauth2 authorization code flow, the browser gets redirected to an allowlisted url on the application server, meaning that the frontend app never receives the code.

While implementing react-oauth2/google, I discovered the default "uxmode" is "popup", which doesn't require any application server interaction and gives an ID token back to the frontend once the user auths with Google. Only "Authorised JavaScript origins" needs to be configured as the serving backend, which I believe is only for CORS and shouldn't be considered secure.

The advice [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token) is that the returned ID token should be sent to the backend and verified (including checking the audience is our client ID). Then we can believe that the user is who they say they are and issue an application token for use against backend APIs).

With the new flow available, what stops someone simply using my publicly available client ID to impersonate me? An unsuspecting user could visit the impersonating site and auth using google, at which point the nefarious app has a valid Google ID token with my client ID as the audience and could exchange it with my backend for an application token.

Answer (score 1):

If the hacker uses your clientId, they will still be redirected back to your application. The redirect URL is hard-coded in Google for your client ID and it protects you in this example and they can't be redirected to the hackers application.

Comment: The uxmode: popup doesn't use redirection. I have this working and javascript is delivered an ID token (all that is required for authentication according to the link in the original question) without any redirects. I don't even have any allowed redirect URLs on this client.

Comment: I've been thinking more and potentially the answer is that the uxmode=popup relies on the browser enforcing the origin header, similar to how uxmode=redirect relies on the browser not sharing the redirect URL with the original page. In either case, if the browser is compromised (or all of this is done via an external application) the security breaks down.

Comment: Yes, if the client or browser is compromised, then it's always game-over anyway (for example due to XSS or compromised browser extensions).